# how to fade in a css message for 3 seconds after a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my code from this site: https://isabelcastillo.com/error-info-messages-css

I want that a css message box is shown for 3 seconds after a button click and then the message is fading out.

Here is my code:

```css
.isa_success,
.isa_error {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.isa_success {
  color: #4F8A10;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
  border-radius: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 3s;
  animation: fadeInOut 3s;
}

.isa_error {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFD2D2;
  border-radius: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 3s;
  animation: fadeInOut 3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="handle">Fade</button> 
<div id="isa_success">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
Test
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
var slideSource = document.getElementById('isa_success');
document.getElementById('handle').onclick = function () {
slideSource.classList.add('fade');
}}
</script>
```

This script does not work.

Comment: Where's your button?

Comment: You will need javascript to respond to events

Comment: The button is the problem, i don't know how. please explain me how. thank you

Comment: We're not a code writing service. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting here. You don't even have the base HTML that starts the process. Please edit your question to include an attempt.

Comment: i have added my first attempt to my question

Comment: I don't see a 'fade' class in your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a class 'fade' to the classist but don't have it in the CSS file.
try this

```js
var slideSource = document.getElementById('isa_success');
document.getElementById('handle').onclick = function () {
slideSource.classList.add('fade');

}
```

```css
.isa_success,
.isa_error {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.isa_success {
  color: #4F8A10;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
  border-radius: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 3s;
  animation: fadeInOut 3s;
}

.isa_error {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFD2D2;
  border-radius: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 3s;
  animation: fadeInOut 3s;
}


.fade{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button id="handle">Fade</button> 
<div id="isa_success">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code. My main fault was that i have forgot to remove the classelement after a specific time.
Thanks for help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.fade{
background: red;
opacity:0;
color: #4F8A10;
background-color: #DFF2BF;
border-radius: .5em;
margin: 8px 0px;
padding:8px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 20%;
}

.elementToFadeInAndOut {
animation: fadeInOut 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
0% { opacity:0; }
50% { opacity:1; } 
100% { opacity:0; } 
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:start();">
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
var div = document.querySelector(".fade");
var btn = document.querySelector(".fadeButton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
div.classList.add("elementToFadeInAndOut");
setTimeout(function(){div.classList.remove("elementToFadeInAndOut");}, 3000);
});
}
</script>

<button class="fadeButton">Button</button>
<div class="fade">This is a message!</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to do this without Javascript. What's important though is the sequence of the HTML elements.

Here I am using a hidden checkbox to determine whether or not a button (label) was clicked.

```css
#clickMe {
  display: none;
}

#clickMeLabel {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clickMe:checked+#clickMeLabel {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

#isa_success {
  color: #4F8A10;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
  border-radius: .5em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}

#clickMe:checked~#isa_success {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="clickMe" type="checkbox">
<label for="clickMe" id="clickMeLabel">Click me</label>
<div id="isa_success">Whatever you want here - images or text</div>
```